# How to set the Content Property of 'Content Editor WebPart' in SharePoint 2007 from Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, content-editor

I want a Page Layout to have a 'Content Editor WebPart' with a static HTML. I don't want to use the ContentLink trick as I can't change the HTML there .... I got to know it can be done by adding the HTML to the 'Content' property of 'Content Editor WebPart'. The issue is when I try to do that in SharePoint Designer it doesn't allow me to do that !

How can I set the Content Property to my HTML CODE ... ?

Regarsd,
H.

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a page layout and you want static HTML in it, why don't you add just put the static html into the page layout and skip the CEWP?

Comment: I want static HTML to be set by default to a CEWP since the user for which I am developing is not a developer and he would just make some basic formatting changes in the HTML.

Comment: I found the solution - Goto the Master Page Gallery and note the full file-name of the Page-Layout.

Now enter the URL as [...]/_catalogs/MasterPages/Page_Layout_FileName.aspx

If this page has a CEWP then it would show up as a Editable SharePoint page and you can now modify the CEWP to add new HTML content.